# Using non-standard names for contexts

Tags: asterisk

I would like to name all my contexts starting with the prefix `ctx-`. While testing this I am having trouble with at least the `incoming` context (and probably more, but I have reverted my changes and stopped further testing)

1. Is it possible to configure asterisk so that it does not use the standard `incoming`, `default`, `outgoing`, but my preferred `ctx-incoming`, `ctx-default`, `ctx-outgoing`?
2. What other standard contexts do I need to consider? I guess this depends on the applications being used? Is there a list of standard contexts?

To clarify, I am doing this because grepping for `incoming` or `default` in my codebase is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is posible use any name for context

Minus is ok also,same with any english letter.

```
pro-sip*CLI> dialplan show my-super-context 
[ Context 'my-super-context' created by 'pbx_config' ]
  's' =>            1. Noop()                                     [pbx_config]
```

There are no any standart context. Only standart section is "[general]" which have contain global variables.

You have consider that ';,[]#@' can't be used.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Actually, I got it right the first time I tried, but forgot to adapt an automatically generated sip configuration file (which was not checked in my repo) where the incoming context for the sip users is specified.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea--but don't forget that in many languages, the hyphen will be interpreted as minus. I'm guessing that Asterisk is doing that. Using an underscore is fine (`ctx_incoming` etc).

Comment: Thx, good caveat, but in asterisk the hyphen is allowed. I am now successfully using `ctx-` for contexts, `sub-` for subroutines, and `lbl-` for labels. Also, asterisk prepends a `macro-` for macros.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use any dilaplan and context you want. That is The flexibility open source provides :)

you can write any context name for your custom dialplan but you have to include those in your main context that you have provided to your users. and good idea for naming convention is to use (_) instead of (-) .

e.g: